# how to reuse runnable jar file in spring app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot app that I compiled with `mvn package` and run it with `java -jar target/springapp.jar`, then I got the error (when I call the url): `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Lab.Plant.Plant`. springapp uses one of the function inside `Lab.Plant.Plant` class.

I used one self-created jar file called `Lab.Plant`, and I store it at `${project.basedir}/lib/`.

I exported the `Lab.Plant` at eclipse with export as runnable jar file with `extract required libraries into generated JAR`, and then I added the jar dependency at springapp `pom.xml` file.

```xml
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>Lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>Plant</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/plant.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

It runs well inside spring boot suite IDE, but not with `java -jar`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Comment: The spring boot maven plugin by default ignored system scope dependencies which is a good thing cause system scoped dependencies are usually a hint that something is wrong. Why do you use a system scoped dependency? Where is that dependency coming from? From a maven build? Are you working in a corporate environment: If yes that should deployed to a repository manager and consumed from there...

Answer (score -1):

You need to pack the dependencies into your jar file. Then you can run it with `java` cmd. Change your maven pom.xml, add below, and run `mvn package`

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!--  bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Or you can just call `mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies` in cmd line.

Comment: First using a very very old version second you have configured it in the life cycle than you call it `mvn clean package`...

Comment: @khmarbaise, you're right, I copy it from somewhere, didn't check the version.

Comment: Furthermore packaging a spring boot app with maven-assembly-plugin will not work cause the layout is different then the `jar-with-dependencies descriptor` defines.